# RegEx Java Replace

Tags: java, regex

I have the following two Strings:

```
execute:13457689
74859374
```

The word execute could be changed in future, so my regex should handle it.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    replace("execute:13457689");
    replace("74859374");
}

private static void replace(String text) {
    System.out.print("input: " + text + ", ");
    System.out.print("result: " + text.replaceFirst("(?<=(:|)).*$", "00000"));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Result:

```
input: execute:13457689, result: 00000
input: 74859374, result: 00000
```

Expected result:

```
input: execute:13457689, result: execute:00000
input: 74859374, result: 00000
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you just want to replace any strings of digits with 5 zeroes?

Comment: Yes, but if there is a string before like execute: or handle:, I want to keep the String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex

```
(\w+:)\d+
```

with this as the replacement

```
$10000
```

The trick here is to use `$1`, which represents the string captured by group 1 (`$2` represents group 2, `$3` represents group 3 and so on). Here, group 1 captures a bunch of word characters followed by `:`.